# Throwing an exception from within a lambda body

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

**I don't think I can get an answer in the suggested duplication. I hope someone can answer**

I have the following code:

```
    private void VerifyLegMessages(long lCurrentTimeMs){

    m_arrLegs.forEach((x) -> {

            if(x.getReqSentMs() != -1){

                if(x.getOkReceivedMs() ==  -1){

                    if(lCurrentTimeMs - x.getReqSentMs() > MAX_TIMEOUT_MS){
                        throw new TimeoutException("Did not receive message on time. Timeout has passed... ");
                    }
                }else{

                    if(x.getOkReceivedMs() - x.getReqSentMs() > MAX_TIMEOUT_MS){
                        throw new TimeoutException("response time was longer than expected... ");
                    }               
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Eclipse yells at me because of the "throw new TimeoutException" and wants me to put the code inside a try and catch block.

Why can't I throw the exception as I could do on other similar methods, where I haven't been using lambda expressions?

Thank you!

Comment: Because `TimeoutException` is a checked exception. Can you change it to being unchecked?

Comment: @assylias Thanks. Ok, I replaced it with RuntimeException. But then, what will be the influence? That I won't be able to handle it?

Comment: It won't make much difference except that your code should now compile!